# Fill JComboBox after changing another JComboBox

Tags: java, arraylist, jcombobox, treemap

I have a class

```
    public class Speciality {
    String specName;
    String eduProgram; }
```

and a TreeMap `Map<String, ArrayList<Speciality>> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Speciality>>();` where String is the name of faculty.

My 1st JComboBox comprises of names of faculties (so they're equal to keys in my Map) and in my `BoxActionListener` I need to fill my 2nd JComboBox with the array of `specNames`.

Here you can see what I actually need, but ofc it doesn't word (because I cast String[] to String)

```
boxSpeciality.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for(int i = 0; i < treeMap.size(); i++){
                    Object key = treeMap.keySet().toArray(new Object[treeMap.size()])[i];
                    ArrayList<Speciality> value = treeMap.get(key);


                    if(key == boxFaculty.getSelectedItem()){
                        boxSpeciality.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel((String[]) value.get(i).specName));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, your combobox `boxFaculty` shows the keys of `treeMap` which are faculty names and your combobox `boxSpeciality` should show the specialities of each faculty ( which is one of the values of the `treeMap` ).

If you want the `boxSpeciality` to be populated based on selection of `boxFaculty`, you should write an `actionListener` on `boxFaculty`.

Another thing to note is do not set a new `DefaultComboboxModel` everytime in the action listener. Set one when you defined the combobox and update its elements in the action listener.

You can do something like below:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<Speciality> specialityModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Speciality>();
boxSpeciality.setModel( specialityModel );
boxFaculty.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object obj = boxFaculty.getSelectedItem();
        if ( obj != null )
        { 
           ArrayList<Speciality> specialities = treeMap.get( obj );
           specialityModel.removeAllElements();
           for ( Speciality speciality : specialities )
           {
              specialityModel.addElement( speciality );
           }
        }

    }

});
```

This will update the `boxSpeciality` box everytime you select an item in `boxFaculty`.

Comment: It updates only once, if I want to change faculty in my application Java says `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` in this row `specModel.removeAllElements();`

Comment: Where are you instantiating the `specModel`, also post the stacktrace of `NullPointerException`.